# How can I sum subqueries data in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I sum sub-queries data in SQL Server 2008?

In this query I want to sum this `Score` column data  in this `CASE` function, where point between rang of number, enough time I try to sum this column it show me error.

Now I want to sum this column `Score` with a `Group by Applicant id`, what's the way I can sum the `Score` column data together ?

But I can't to do this query. please help me, here I'm a beginner.

```
SELECT   
    ApplicantId, point,
    'Score' =  CASE 
                 WHEN  point BETWEEN 4.00 AND 4.50 THEN ('3' )
                 WHEN  point BETWEEN 3.5 AND 4.00 THEN ('2' ) 
              END
FROM tblAcademicInfo
WHERE tblAcademicInfo.ApplicantId = tblAcademicInfo.ApplicantId
```

Output:

```
ApplicantId  point   Score
--------------------------------
   xzc1  3.25    NULL
   xzc1  4.36    3
   xzc1  3.59    2
   xzc1  4.00    3
```

Comment: I answered your question, but I don't think it's exactly what you're looking to do, what error are you getting, what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems

1. Your `WHERE` clause makes no sense
2. To sum scores per applicant use `SUM()` and `GROUP BY` clause
3. To be able to sum values you should return numeric values in `CASE` instead of string literals
4. In your query you have `point` column in your select. But it's not part of `GROUP BY` because you want to group by `applicantid`. Therefore you should either apply an aggregate function on this column (e.g. also `SUM()`) or remove it from the resultset.

Try

```
SELECT ApplicantId,
       SUM(CASE WHEN  point BETWEEN 4.0 AND 4.5 THEN 3
                WHEN  point BETWEEN 3.5 AND 4.0 THEN 2 
       END) Score
  FROM tblAcademicInfo
 GROUP BY ApplicantId
```

Output:

```
| APPLICANTID | SCORE |
|-------------|-------|
|        xzc1 |     8 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/750af/3)** demo

Comment: i want sum only Score

Comment: Ok. What do you want to do with `point` then? You don't need it in the resultset then, right? See updated answer.

Comment: it show this error.. Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: If it shows this error then you don't use the code that I provided. Did you take a look at sqlfiddle demo that I provided?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
SELECT   ApplicantId,point,
    SUM(CASE 
WHEN  point BETWEEN 4.00 AND 4.50 THEN 3
WHEN  point BETWEEN 3.5 AND 4.00 THEN 2 
END
) [Score]
FROM tblAcademicInfo
WHERE tblAcademicInfo.ApplicantId
GROUP BY ApplicantId, point
```

Comment: it showing this error  Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT ApplicationId,Point,sum(Case When score IS Null Then 0 else score END) as SumScore
FROM tblAcademicInfo
GroupBy Applicatio0nId,Point,score
```